# How to get values in a line while looping line by line in a file (shell script)

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which looks like this (file.txt)

```
{"key":"AJGUIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
{"key":"TJHJHJHDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
{"key":"YUUUIGIDH566","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
{"key":"HJHHIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
{"key":"ATYUGUIDH556","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
{"key":"QfgUIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
```

I want to loop trough this line by line an extract the key values.

so the result should be like ,

```
AJGUIGIDH568
AJGUIGIDH568
YUUUIGIDH566
HJHHIGIDH568
ATYUGUIDH556
QfgUIGIDH568
```

So I wrote a code like this to loop line by line and extract the value between `{"key":"` and `","rule":` because key values is in between these 2 patterns.

```
while read p; do 
  echo $p | sed -n "/{"key":"/,/","rule":,/p"
done < file.txt
```

But this is not working.  can someone help me to figure out me this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is JSON, take a look at `jq`.

Comment: double-quotes don't nest: `"x"y"x"` contains two double-quoted strings separated by `y`, not a single double-quoted string that contains two `x`s separated by `"y"`. That's why your sed command fails.

Comment: Is that REALLY what your input file looks like? It seems unlikely at best that some other tool is outputting that - I suspect you have done some pre-processing of your original text to get to the format in your question but by doing so that's making things harder now, it'd have been easier to work with your original text which I assume contained valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample input is almost valid json.  You could tweak it to make it valid and then extract the values with `jq` with something like:

```
sed -e 's/squid/"squid/' -e 's/$/"}/' file.txt | jq -r .key
```

Or, if your actual input really is valid json, then just use `jq`:

```
jq -r .key file.txt
```

If the "random-txt" may include double quotes, making it difficult to massage the input to make it valid json, perhaps you want something like:

```
awk '{print $4}' FS='"' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -n '/{"key":"\([^"]*\).*/s//\1/p' file.txt
```

or

```
while IFS=\" read open_brace key colon val _; do echo "$val"; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For the shown data, you can try this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '"[:,]"' '{print $2}' file

AJGUIGIDH568
TJHJHJHDH568
YUUUIGIDH566
HJHHIGIDH568
ATYUGUIDH556
QfgUIGIDH568
```

Answer (score 1):

With the give example you can simple use

```
cut -d'"' -f4 file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- there may be other lines in the file so we need to focus on just the lines with `"key"` and `"rule"`
- the only text between `"key"` and `"rule"` is the desired string (eg, `squid` never shows up between the two patterns of interest)

Adding some additional lines:

```
$ cat file.txt
{"key":"AJGUIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
{"key":"TJHJHJHDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
{"key":"YUUUIGIDH566","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
{"key":"HJHHIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
{"key":"ATYUGUIDH556","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
{"key":"QfgUIGIDH568","rule":squid:111-some_random_text_here
ignore this line}
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^(.*"key":")([^"]*)(","rule".*)$/\2/p' file.txt
AJGUIGIDH568
TJHJHJHDH568
YUUUIGIDH566
HJHHIGIDH568
ATYUGUIDH556
QfgUIGIDH568
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support (and capture groups without need to escape sequences)
- `-n` - suppress printing of pattern space
- `^(.*"key":")` - [1st capture group] everything from start of line up to and including `"key":"`
- `([^"]*)` - [2nd capture group] everything that is not a double quote (`"`)
- `(","rule".*)$` - [3rd capture group] everything from `",rule"` to end of line
- `\2/p` - replace the line with the contents of the 2nd capture group and `p`rint